# What exactly breaks the while loop in main?

Tags: c, while-loop

What exactly breaks the while loop in this code? This is code from the book *The C Programming Language* from the C creators. It is a code from section 1.9. I guess `int len` will always be bigger than 0, but somehow when I compile this code the while loop breaks when I press Ctrl+Z (which is EOF for Windows).

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000 /* maximum input line length */

int mgetline(char line[], int maxline);
void copy(char to[], char from[]);

/* print the longest input line */
main() {
    int len; /* current line length */
    int max; /* maximum length seen so far */
    char line[MAXLINE]; /* current input line */
    char longest[MAXLINE]; /* longest line saved here */
    max = 0;
    while ((len = mgetline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
        if (len > max) {
            max = len;
            if (max == len)
                copy(longest, line);
        }
    if (max > 0) /* there was a line */
        printf("%s", longest);
    return 0;
}

/* mgetline: read a line into s, return length */
int mgetline(char s[], int lim) {
    int c, i;
    for (i = 0; i < lim - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

/* copy: copy 'from' into 'to'; assume to is big enough */
void copy(char to[], char from[]) {
    int i;
    i = 0;
    while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
        ++i;
}
```

Comment: Please at least try to indent the code nicely and consitently. Right now it's hard to follow along.

Comment: You might also want to [learn how to debug programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). If you step through the code, line by line, and stepping into the `mgetline` function when it's called, then you will be able to see when the function returns a value that is less than or equal to `0` (which will break the loop).

Comment: sorry, I had to do it couple of times before the website allowed me to post the code. this is my first post.

Comment: ok, thanks for debbuging tip, i will definately check it out

Comment: `s[i] = c;` What do you think happens here? (`c` is an `int`)

Comment: @Michi a number is saved in string s, and because string s is char, ASCII value of that number becomes a character. right?

Answer (score 3):

**Loop 1:** (In `copy`)

Strings in C are NUL-terminated by convention. NUL is a special `char` value with the value 0.

The value of the expression `to[i] = from[i]` is the new value of `to[i]`.

That is 0 when NUL is reached, and the loop exits.

**Loop 2:** (In `main`)

Similarly the value of `len = mgetline(line, MAXLINE)` is the new value of `len`. That is 0 if `mgetline` returns 0 which is does when no characters are read. So that loop exits.

Comment: maybe you answered it, but then I don't understand it.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker: Indeed, luckily the reason is similar enough for the original answer to stand.

Comment: @Bathsheba `NUL` or `NULL` ?

Comment: `NUL` without a shadow of doubt. That's the character name.